# Is it possible to assign multiple roles to a user or group in Azure AD?

Tags: azure, authorization, roles, azure-active-directory

When I add an `appRoles` section to my application manifest in Azure AD, I can assign users and groups to roles in the management portal.

```
  "appRoles": [
    {
      "allowedMemberTypes": [
        "User"
      ],
      "description": "Can read data.",
      "displayName": "Data Reader",
      "id": "67fba7fa-e54e-4258-b95d-32b082eb771d",
      "isEnabled": true,
      "value": "reader"
    },
    {
      "allowedMemberTypes": [
        "User"
      ],
      "description": "Can create and edit data.",
      "displayName": "Data Writer",
      "id": "e36736c5-e923-435e-8e44-6cae90792931",
      "isEnabled": true,
      "value": "writer"
    }
  ],
```

However, the UI only allows me to assign a single role to a user or group.

I can't find how to assign multiple roles to a user or group. I can add the user to multiple groups and assign roles to members of that group, which will result in multiple role claims in the token for that user, but this seems awkward.

Am I missing something? Is there a way to assign multiple roles to a user or group?

Answer (score 28, accepted):

You can assign multiple roles to the same user in the same app, but it is very limited.  Basically add the same user again and select a different role:

[image]

The mechanism is very cumbersome and will not scale.  If you have AAD Premium Lvl 2, you can associate application roles with groups and a when you assign a user to that group, they will gain the roles automatically.  The automatic assignment only works for Premium Lvl 2 though.

Comment: Yeah, this question was asked and answered when the new portal did not exist yet. Seems silly that they only made this workable for Premium 2 users.

Comment: I see someone plays world of warcraft ;)

Comment: + 50 DKP to you

Comment: This doesn't seem to work in the current version of Azure AD

Comment: @Atif I seem to be able to add the same user multiple times with different roles.

Answer (score 7):

This turns out to be a limitation of the Azure [management portal](https://manage.windowsazure.com/). In this [blog comment](http://www.dushyantgill.com/blog/2014/12/10/roles-based-access-control-in-cloud-applications-using-azure-ad/#comment-1541), the AAD PM explains it is possible to assign multiple roles to a user or group through the GraphAPI.

For more info, see section '**Assigning application roles**' in this MSDN [blog article](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/aadgraphteam/archive/2014/12/12/announcing-the-new-version-of-graph-api-api-version-1-5.aspx).

Comment: Unfortunately those last two blog links are dead.

Answer (score 1):

Had the same problem and with the current version of the azure portal the workaround was

1. Create two groups (group_for_perm1, group_for_perm2)
2. Add the same user to both groups (myuser@domain.com)
3. Go into Azure AD->Enterprise applications
4. Change the "Application type" filter to "All applications"
5. Search for your app
6. Select "Users and Groups"
7. Hit "+ Add user/group" at the top, and assign group_for_perm1 permission1
8. Hit "+ Add user/group" at the top, Assign group_for_perm2 permission2

Note if the "+ Add user/group" button is greyed out, you either didn't add App Roles to the App registration, or aren't in the owner group for the "Enterprise application".  It appears you can be the owner of the App Registration and not be the owner of the Enterprise Application.

The token should now have a roles section with your two permissions.  Take the JWT to jwt.io and you should see something like

```
  "rh": "I",
  "roles": [
    "permission1",
    "permission2"
  ],
```